# Evaluating $\prod\limits_{n\ge2}\left(1-\frac2{n(n+1)}\right)^2$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

> Let $$x_n=\left(1-\frac13\right)^2\left(1-\frac16\right)^2\left(1-\frac1{10}\right)^2\cdots\left(1-\frac2{n(n+1)}\right)^2,n\ge2$$
>
> Then the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ equals?

I tried to take log both sides:
$$\log x_n=2\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\log⁡(1-\frac{2}{k(k+1)}) $$
Despite taking limit both sides, I did not get it of the standard form of $1^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Rewriting
$$1-\frac2{k(k+1)}=\frac{(k-1)(k+2)}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot\frac{k+2}{k+1}$$

Thus
$$\prod_{k=2}^n\left[1-\frac2{k(k+1)}\right]=\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k+2}{k+1}$$